# Extending interface with new model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have a loginmodel where a user has to fill in a username and password but I wat to extend that model with a new model so that only a username is required.
So this is my new model:

```
public class V_LoginModel_BalieUser:LoginModel
    {

        public string BalieCode { get; set; }
    }
```

And the original model looks like this:

```
 //
    // Summary:
    //     A model to login into the webshop.
    public class LoginModel
    {
        public LoginModel();

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the password.
        [AllowHtml]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Validation_RequiredField")]
        [StringLength(30, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Validation_MaxLengthExceeded")]
        public virtual System.String Password { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a value indicating whether to remember the user to login him automatically
        //     on the next visit.
        [Display(Name = "Login_RememberMe")]
        public virtual System.Boolean RememberMe { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the username.
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Validation_InvalidField")]
        [Display(Name = "EmailAddress")]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Validation_RequiredField")]
        [StringLength(80, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Validation_MaxLengthExceeded")]
        [TrimAttribute(new[] { })]
        public virtual System.String UserName { get; set; }
    }
```

and the new view looks like this:

```
@{

    Layout = LayoutPaths.General;
}

@model Sana.Commerce.DomainModel.Account.V_LoginModel_BalieUser

<div class="semicolumn">
    <div class="form-holder">
        @using (Html.BeginForm(htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => modelItem.BalieCode)
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.BalieCode)
                    </td>

                </tr>


            </table>
            <div class="form-row">
                <h4></h4>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    <div>

    </div>
</div>
```

in the ProfileController I have these two methods:

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult LoginBalieUser()
        {
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LoginBalieUser(V_LoginModel_BalieUser model)
        {

            VI_ExtendedShopApiState_BalieUser balieUser;
            ISalesPersonProfile salesAgent99 = CommerceFrameworkBase.SalesPersons.GetSalesPerson("HD");
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return View(model);

            if (!balieUser.LoginBalieUser(model.BalieCode))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "");
                return View(model);
            }



            return View();
        }
```

This Interface:   VI_ExtendedShopApiState_BalieUser looks like this:

```
public interface VI_ExtendedShopApiState_BalieUser: IUserStateApi
    {

        bool LoginBalieUser(string username);
    }
```

And in the Interface IUserStateApi has for example this method :

```
  bool Login(string username, string password, bool persistent);
```

So I have extended this INterface with a new method(That I have declared above).

But now in this method:

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LoginBalieUser(V_LoginModel_BalieUser model)
        {

            VI_ExtendedShopApiState_BalieUser balieUser;
            ISalesPersonProfile salesAgent99 = CommerceFrameworkBase.SalesPersons.GetSalesPerson("HD");
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return View(model);

            if (!balieUser.LoginBalieUser(model.BalieCode))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "");
                return View(model);
            }



            return View();
        }
```

I get this error:

Use of unassigned local variable 'balieUser'

But so my question is: what I have to assign to:

```
  VI_ExtendedShopApiState_BalieUser balieUser;
```

Thank you

if I do it like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LoginBalieUser(V_LoginModel_BalieUser model)
        {

            VI_ExtendedShopApiState_BalieUser balieUser;
            balieUser.LoginBalieUser(model.BalieCode);
            ISalesPersonProfile salesAgent99 = CommerceFrameworkBase.SalesPersons.GetSalesPerson("HD");
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return View(model);

            if (!balieUser.LoginBalieUser(model.BalieCode))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "");
                return View(model);
            }



            return View();
        }
```

I get still the error:

Code    Description Project File    Line    Column  Suppression State
CS0165  Use of unassigned local variable 'balieUser'

if I do it like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LoginBalieUser(V_LoginModel_BalieUser model)
        {
            //model = new V_LoginModel_BalieUser();
            VI_ExtendedShopApiState_BalieUser balieUser;
            balieUser = new V_LoginModel_BalieUser();

            balieUser.LoginBalieUser(model.BalieCode);
            ISalesPersonProfile salesAgent99 = CommerceFrameworkBase.SalesPersons.GetSalesPerson("HD");
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return View(model);

            if (!balieUser.LoginBalieUser(model.BalieCode))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "");
                return View(model);
            }



            return View();
        }
```

I get this error:

```
Code    Description Project File    Line    Column  Suppression State
CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'Sana.Commerce.DomainModel.Account.V_LoginModel_BalieUser' to 'Sana.Commerce.Customization.Interfaces.VI_ExtendedShopApiState_BalieUser'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be cause you are just declaring the type variable and not instantiating it at all as can be seen below

```
       VI_ExtendedShopApiState_BalieUser balieUser;
```

Moreover I doubt on the posted error message cause the below code line should throw a `System.NullReferenceException`

```
balieUser.LoginBalieUser(model.BalieCode)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But  instantiating ? It is a Interface. So I can't ofcourse instantiating  VI_ExtendedShopApiState_BalieUser . Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @mightycodeNewton, I mean instanciating a concrete type which implements your this interace

Comment: I try it like this:   VI_ExtendedShopApiState_BalieUser balieUser = new V_LoginModel_BalieUser();

Comment: ? But how to improve it then?

Comment: What I do wrong then? Can somebody help me? Thank you